# Remove Commas but Accept underscore URL Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a string REGEX that won't accept commas in the hostnames. It is correctly accepting underscores but I can't split the string because it won't split the underscore. How can I create a REGEX that won't accept commas and allow me to split the string on periods?

This is my code:

```
String REGEX = "(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?
(http: \\/\\/|https:  \\/\\/|ftp:\\/\\/)?(www.)?(file://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9 
\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+ (/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?";

String[] domainNameParts = statusForHost.split("\\.");
```

Result: It is incorrectly accepting "https://caacan,a.cioa".

Result: It correctly accepts "http://m_y.you" but it won't split to print out ".you" as a top level domain.

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: The language is java

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the REGEX should do, but `s.matches(REGEX)` returns `false` for both examples above.

I don't know what you expect, but the method `match` splits the string at the given pattern and removes the pattern, so you get `"http://m_y"` and `"you"` as result, not `".you"`.

Maybe you could provide a better (working) sample code including the results you expect and you get?